# Retrieving value of text input submits page with that value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm working on a HTML/JS method of capturing data within multiple input text boxes and running into a strange issue when trying to retrieve the values held within the inputs.  I'll go ahead and post the code here before explaining my issue.

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div id="manual-record-headers">
        <b class="manual-record-header">Serial Number</b>
        <b class="manual-record-header">Drive Health</b>
        <b class="manual-record-header">Location</b>
        <b class="manual-record-header">Username</b>
    </div>
    <div id="manual-record-table">
        <div class="manual-record-row" id="manual-row-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control manual-record-input serial-num-input" placeholder="Serial number for drive...">
            <input type="text" class="form-control manual-record-input drive-health-input" placeholder="Drive health state...">
            <input type="text" class="form-control manual-record-input drive-location-input" onsubmit="return false;" placeholder="Storage location for drive...">
            <input type="text" class="form-control manual-record-input username-input" placeholder="Check in username...">
            <button class="delete-row"> <img src="/static/main/img/delete.png" width="34" height="34" /> </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
for ( x=1; x < manual_record_count + 1; x++ ) {
    temp_inventory_list = []

    try {
        serial = $('#manual-row-' + x + ' > .serial-num-input').val();
        health = $('#manual-row-' + x + ' > .drive-health-input').val();
        location = $('#manual-row-' + x + ' > .drive-location-input').val();
        username = $('#manual-row-' + x + ' > .username-input').val();
    }
    catch(err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }

    [program, drive_type, product_type] = get_data_from_drive_serial(serial)

    temp_inventory_list = [serial, health, location, username, program, drive_type, product_type];
    inventory_list.push(temp_inventory_list);
}
```

For some reason, on the third text input, where I am trying to retrieve the value of the ".drive-location-input", the page is being submitted with the value from that text input.  So if I was to input a value of "333333333" into the .drive-location-input text input, the page would go from 127.0.0.1/main to 127.0.0.1/main/333333333.  I should also note, that the page gets redirected/submitted before the try/catch and alert ever go off, so I can't see any possible errors that would be causing this.

As far as I can tell, there is no reason why this should be occurring, especially since the other 3 text inputs seem to be able to be retrieved with no issue.  Is this an issue with the one text input itself, or should I be looking into why the page is even submitting with the value obtained in the first place?

Please let me know if any other info is necessary, and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: perhaps it could be due to the "onsubmit: return false" on the drive-location-input item?

Comment: @knosmos Thanks for the quick response, I had added that onsubmit in order to try to fix the problem but I actually just figured out the root cause.  Turned out that using "location" as a variable name is a big no-no.  "location" returns the window elements location, and apparently results in a page redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that using "location" as a variable name is a big no-no. "location" returns the window elements location, and apparently results in a page redirect.  So for anyone else that may see this issue in the future, look into if any variable names you are using have conflicts... Not a fun way to waste half a day!